# VueJS - dynamic button component?

Tags: vue.js

I'd like to have a dropdown button in the top right of a bunch of pages across my web app - but not all of them. The button's options need to be specific to the page the button is on.

For example, the button on the "Contacts" page needs to have options like, "New Contact", "Delete Contact", etc. But the button on the "Invoice" page needs to have options like "New Invoice", "Add Payment", "Change Info".

I want the look and formatting of the button to be consistent across my whole site, but the contents of the button itself need to change depending on which page the button is presented.

How would this be achieved?

Comment: You could maybe use dynamic components https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: @BelminBedak I'm not sure how that would be applicable in this situation. I'm not trying to pass in a component, but rather pass in the links for a dropdown button in a component. I want to declare the formatting for the button once -- but have the links inside the button change depending on which page it is being presented on. It's almost like using `props`, this is would be full links and text, etc.

Comment: Use props and build your links.